# data validation is not working through data annotations

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to validate the length through data annotations like this

```
 [DataMember]
 [StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "ClaimNumber cannot exceed length higher than 7")]
 public string claimNumber
```

Still error is not thrown if string of more lenght is passed. Can any one please help with this? its with Entity framework.

Comment: Well, that is a field, validations only work on properites I think. If it is a property you need to show all relevant code in your question to reproduce your problem or else you risk getting your question closed.

Comment: yes with properties, it worked . Thank you

Comment: I turned my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown a field, data validation only works with properties.

Answer (score 0):

Wcf has not data annotations validation out of the box. To add this you can use this nuget package: [Wcf.AttributeValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wcf.AttributeValidation/)